Equivalent Loop Inductance
this is a question I believe is straight forward, but for some reason can't wrap my head around it. I am trying to simulate parasitic inductance in a circuit with 2 FETS (Q1, Q2) during a switching transient and a capacitor bank as shown with C1 and C2. In the layout there is a low impedance path containing small low ESL ceramic caps as shown by C1, and a higher impedance path containing large film caps that are much farther away in the layout and thus that path will have a higher parasitic inductance. My question is, is the equivalent total loop inductance as simple as L2||L3 + L1 + l4 = ~1.95nH. And if so, is this a reasonable way of modelling the parasitics.
If I were to put the layout layers and traces into a 3d field solver shorting caps L2,L3 and Q2 would this be a reasonable way to estimate the loop inductance?

